# React - TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs, class

I am trying to learn class components and I have done something wrong but don't know what.

```
import React from "react"

class App extends React.Component() {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            name: "test",
            age: 31
        }
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
                <h3>{this.state.age} years old</h3>
            </div>
        )    
    }
}
export default App
```

And this is the error

> TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were extending `React.Component()` it should be `React.Component`

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "test",
      age: 31
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
        <h3>{this.state.age} years old</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: you extended `React.Conponent()` which should be just `React.Component`

Comment: Yes that was it.